# Are jquery GET calls faster than angular $http.get

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have an angular app with which has a few `$http.get` calls some with a success/error funcs others just as below. After trying to increase the speed of the app, I noticed that changing the `$http.get` calls to jquery calls the app sped up. So are jquery calls faster than angular `$http` calls, if so I'll change all my get request to jquery.

```
$http.get('/event/'+ _id);

$.ajax({url: '/event/'+ _id  });
```

Has anyone else noticed this?

Comment: You should extend your question a bit. What is faster, the code or the request response time? How much *faster*, ~5ms, ~10ms ~100ms? How do the request headers look like for both requests? Is the difference consistant or only on subsequent requests?

Comment: The response time was faster, I'll have to double check the headers sent.

Comment: simply do a for loop, assume 1 million $http and $.ajaxx. the u will get the result. both suppose using xmlhttpreques for backend request if i not wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't expect much of a gain, if any. HTTP requests are expensive, your biggest bottle neck will always be the network. So, it doesn't matter how fast the code is when the network takes over a second. With that being said, check HTTP headers to check which one is more verbose. If you get rid of `$http.get` you also lose the seamless ability to unit test since you now have to mock `$.ajax`.